# Understanding RxJava basics

Tags: android, rx-java, observable

I am just doing my first steps with RxJava, making use of this [tutorial](http://blog.danlew.net/2014/09/15/grokking-rxjava-part-1/). I understand what an `Observable` and what a `Subscriber` is. But I have problems with "connecting" them. I just thought about such a task: An Activity A starts an Activity B. Activity B has a button with which you can create a `Date` containing the current date. Another button emits this `Date` and finishes Activity B. Activity A subscribes to the emitted `Date`-Observable and displays the current date. (I know this is normally done by using Activity results). I have the following problem:

I can create a `Date`-Observable within Activity B by this code(The instance mDate is of type `Date` and is created somewhere else in Activity B):

```
Observable<Date> dateObservable =
            Observable.create(sub -> {
        sub.onNext(mDate);
        sub.onCompleted();
    });
```

But in Activity A I have to subscribe to it. But I have no reference to the Observable in Activity B. I thought about creating the Observable statically in my `Application` class but there I don't know the value of `mDate` yet. Can I somehow create an Observable of a certain type without implementing the "call()"-Method (where `onNext()` and `onCompleted()` are called)? So then I would already have an Observable instance I could subscribe to in my Aativity.And then later I could implement the "call()"-Method in Activity B? Ore are there other RxJava features I can use to achieve my described goals?

Comment: This thing might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QdmkXL7XikQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a thing called `ReplaySubject`.

In your custom `MyApplication` class:

```
ReplaySubject<Date> dateSubject = ReplaySubject.create();
```

In activity B:

```
ReplaySubject<Date> subject = ((MyApplication)getApplication()).getSubject();
subject.onNext(mDate);
subject.onCompleted();
```

In activity A:

```
ReplaySubject<Date> subject = ((MyApplication)getApplication()).getSubject();
subject.subscribe(...);
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped. But now I am still a bit unsatisfied. Because I have to use the ``Application`` class as a "passing interface" and I would like to avoid that. As I heard RxJava can be used to send events on an EventBus. How to achieve this?

Comment: @unlimited101, in most implementations event bus is basically a simple observable. You could put it in a static variable instead of an `Application` and make a wrapper around it. There's no other way to share an object across activities as far as I'm aware.

Comment: By eventbus (https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) you can send data between Android components like Services, Activities, etc. But I would like to realize this in RxJava.

Comment: @unlimited101 if you look at the code, for example `EventBus.java`, you'll notice that it's implemented as a singleton and its instance is stored in a static variable. You could make something similar by making a wrapper around your `Observable` which would be instantiated as a static variable.

Comment: in most case your event bus will be either a field of the application, a static variable somewhere, or an injected singleton (I'd go with the latter, obv., but others are fine if you don't use dependency injection in your project)